# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file?

Tags: java, version

I am getting this error when I include an opensource library that I had to compile from source.  Now, all the suggestions on the web indicate that the code was compiled in one version and executed in another version (new on old).  However, I only have one version of JRE on my system.  If I run the commands:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.5.0_18

$ java -version
java version "1.5.0_18"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_18-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_18-b02, mixed mode)
```

and check in Eclipse for the properties of the java library, I get `1.5.0_18`

Therefore, I have to conclude something else, internal to a class itself, is throwing the exception?? Is that even possible?

Comment: do you have a compiled version of the library somewhere else that might be on your classpath first?

Comment: Good idea, but no.  I did a check by using 'find . -name '*.jar' | xargs locate' from the lib folder with the JARs.  Besides, I didn't think Eclipse used CLASSPATH?

Any other good suggestions?

Comment: how to use this find -name '*.jar' command on cmd as i am looking to rebuild the jre src code again...and for that i need to fire this cmd.....http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t103334.html.....my jdk is at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31

Answer (score 186, accepted):

I've learned that error messages like this are usually right. When it couldn't POSSIBLY (in your mind) be what the error being reported says, you go hunting for a problem in another area...only to find out hours later that the original error message was indeed right.

Since you're using Eclipse, I think Thilo has it right The most likely reason you are getting this message is because one of your projects is compiling 1.6 classes. It doesn't matter if you only have a 1.5 JRE on the system, because Eclipse has its own compiler (not javac), and only needs a 1.5 JRE to compile 1.6 classes. 
It may be weird, and a setting needs to be unchecked to allow this, but I just managed to do it.

For the project in question, check the Project Properties (usually Alt+Enter), Java Compiler section. Here's an image of a project configured to compile 1.6, but with only a 1.5 JRE.

[image]

Comment: Totally agree ... that is why I asked, in my comment, the question for ways to pin-point.  I did not know of the Eclipse internal classes.  The library was compiled on the command line with 'javac' and integrated into my Eclipse project.  I will try compiling my project from the command line.  You clearly have solved this problem in the past and your suggestions are fantastic.

Comment: If you have the JDK (which has sources), you should be able to add some breakpoints in Eclipse and hopefully see what class it's attempting to load. The easiest way is probably a breakpoint in the constructor for UnsupportedClassVersionError (or an Eclipse Exception breakpoint, the 'J!' icon), then you can inspect how it got there.

Comment: OK.  I found an expert in the building and he was able to point Eclipse to the same JRE as my command line.  I then rebuilt against 1.6 and ran against 1.6 and it is all working.  Obviously, I was wrong about not having anything but 1.5.  He showed me where to look.

Thanks for the help -- now I am on to my next problem! :)

Comment: I had the same issue. The mistake I did was I was using 1.5 JRE and 1.6 compiler. Which did not solve the unsupportedclassversion error. So I installed the 1.6 JRE in my eclipse and used 1.6 compiler. Then everything started working fine.

Comment: Great answer.  I have a number of xServers that will not be upgraded to 1.6.  Who would've thought!

Comment: Thanks!  Had foolishly assumed that the jre on the build path was used.  As an aside, can anyone explain why the "Use compliance from execution environment" row is grayed out in my eclipse?

Comment: If you are like me and encounter this problem when using Eclipse and ANT, make sure to check `Project Propeties - Java Compiler`, `Eclipse Preferences - Java - Compiler` and `Java - Installed JREs` as well as `External Tool Configurations - JRE`.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried doing a full "clean" and then rebuild in Eclipse (Project->Clean...)?

Are you able to compile and run with "javac" and "java" straight from the command line?  Does that work properly?

If you right click on your project, go to "Properties" and then go to "Java Build Path", are there any suspicious entries under any of the tabs?  This is essentially your CLASSPATH.

In the Eclipse preferences, you may also want to double check the "Installed JREs" section in the "Java" section and make sure it matches what you think it should.

You definitely have either a stale .class file laying around somewhere or you're getting a compile-time/run-time mismatch in the versions of Java you're using.

Comment: yes (full clean); have not tried it (project from cmd line); maybe/no (I removed entries from Eclipse "Java Build Path"); did that (JREs - that is where I got the version#).

Answer (score 5):

Did you compile with Eclipse? It uses a different compiler (not javac). That should not result in this error (if everything is configured properly), but you can try to compile it with javac instead.

If that fixed the problem, try to see if Eclipse has some incorrect compiler settings. Specifically have it target Java 5.

Comment: That is what I am learning.  I am going to try building the two pieces the same way (cmd line and/or eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error. Reason for that I was compiling the project using Maven. I had JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK7 and hence java 1.7 was being used for compilation and when running the project I was using JDK1.5. Changing the below entry in .classpath file or change in the eclipse as in the screenshot resolved the issue.

```
classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5
```

or change in the run configuarions of eclipse as 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also check any jar files in your project that have been compiled for a higher version of Java. If these are your own libraries, you can fix this by changing the target version attribute to javac

```
<javac destdir="${classes.dir}"
            debug="on" classpathref="project.classpath" target="1.6">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario where this could happen is when you are launching an instance of eclipse (for debug etc.) from a host eclipse - in which case, altering the project's level or JRE library on the project's classpath alone doesn't help. What matters is the JRE used to launch the target eclipse environment.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for the obvious too.  I got this error once when I accidently grabbed the wrong resource for the server's add and remove action.  It can be easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the project specific settings files (Eclipse workspace/project folder/.settings/) from the project folder also will do. 
Obviously, we need to do a project clean and build after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

changing the project to use java 1.7: For this to work follow those steps :

- Change Compiler Compliance Level
- Change your projects JRE/JDK to something of the same level(1.7 in my case)
- Do the same change in all the projects referenced by your project
- Change your run/debug configuration to use the JRE/JDK (or of the same level)

Not working?

- delete projects Bin directory
- Clean
- reBuild

Still not working?

in your project's directory: edit .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs > make sure your target level is applied

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

i solved  this problem by changing jre required for server (in my case is tomcat).
From Server tab in eclipse, double click on the server (in order to open page for server configuration), click on Runtime environment, then change JRE required