# Error while running Selenium test case

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have written Selenium test case in Java. I started Selenium RC server. I am trying to run the Selenium test case I am getting the below error.

```
ava.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
```

I investigated on the problem above. It is because of Java version mismatches. But what Java version do I have to use to fix it?

I compiled the Selenium testcase in Java 1.5 version.
My Selenium Java client driver version is 1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a java problem not a selenium one.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file) on how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use Java 1.7 and above version.Because higher version Selenium does not support older version Java.