# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: java

I am using jdk 1.5.0_22 and this is set in env variables also. my server also has the same java version.

but still I am getting this error 
"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file". Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file)

Comment: This might be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file

Comment: I found a similar question here
[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file

Answer (score 3):

Are you using any libraries (JAR files)? It could be that those were compiled with Java 6 and thus cannot be run on a Java 5 JVM.