# Grails: Where is the startGrails script in Eclipse/STS on the Mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos, grails

In order to fix another problem [(Stackoverflow Question 6367763)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367763/grails-1-4-0-m1-with-sts-2-7-0-m2-noclassdeffounderror-for-gantbuilder) I needed to modify the startGrails script. I made the necessary updates however the modifications are not being picked up when I run Grails commands from within Eclipse/STS.

I put debug in the script and know it is functioning correctly when I call it directly from the command line. However STS appears to be running the original version.

Does STS have another copy of the startGrails script? How can I update this one or ensure STS links to the version of the startGrails script that I updated?