# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: selenium

I am getting the follwing error while running selenium testcase.

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
```

I have checked all the versions of java in eclispse and they are correct.

Please it would be greatful if you can help me out.

Comment: Some version is not correct. This could be a jar file, not the code you compiled. What class are you getting this for?

Comment: I am trying to run the selenium testcase.I am using junit3 to run the test

Answer (score 9):

`UnsupportedClassVersionError` occurs typically when you have .class (typically in .jar-file) that has been compiled with higher version of java than virtual machine trying to run it. For example you have a .class-file that is compiled with JDK 6 and you are trying to run it with 1.4 JVM.

Check your PATH variable and test `java -version` command etc. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file) thread for couple typical issues that cause this problem.

Comment: Worked perfectly after upgrading the JRE, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to mismatch in your Java Versions. Follow the following steps

- Type Regedit in run and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\
- See the version number mentioned in the registry
- Download the same version and place it in your computer
- Set JAVA_HOME to the jdk directory in environment variables
- Add %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin to the path variable

Now check again.