# Selenium hub and node issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am newbie to selenium. I am trying to run some test cases, for this I tried to start selenium hub and node..Following is batch file to start hub and node.

```
set path=%path%;C:\SeleniumConfig;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_45\lib;
set webdriver.ie.driver=C:\SeleniumConfig\IEDriverServer.exe
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub -hubConfig config-hub.json
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -nodeConfig config-node.json -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

When I tried to run hub and node using following command , I dont see any issue on command prompt. but dont see anythings is running on `http://MyHost:4444/`

```
 "start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub -hubConfig config-hub.json"
```

With the above command some window opens and close immediately.
Please advice

Comment: insert `pause` to the end of the bat file and remove `start` before `java -jar`, this will let you see what error it thrown before it closed

Comment: Thanks for help.. After updating I am getting following NoClassDefError exception.. C:\SeleniumConfig>java C:\SeleniumConfig\selenium.jar -role hub -hubConfig C:\Se
leniumConfig\config-hub.json
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\SeleniumConfig\sel
enium/jar

Comment: seems that this is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java  :)

Comment: Sorry.. Bymistake "-jar" was remove from this command. actual issue is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version n
umber in .class file"

Comment: then it can be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281767/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file :)

Comment: Its works.. Somehow "set path=%path%;C:\SeleniumConfig;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;
" not overriding system path. In system path java 1.5 was set, so it picking same i.e 1.5.  Now runnning command from JAVA_HOME\bin\javae.exe .. so it picks 1.7 java.

Comment: it's great! :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar file must be at same path . Or you can give jar file path. e.g. start java -jar C:/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role ......

Comment: I tried to run "start java C:\SeleniumConfig\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub -hubConfig C:\SeleniumConfig\config-hub.json" but no luck... its opens some window and close instantly.. d

Comment: Please run your batch file from cmd , so that you can see exact error