# JRE issue in Microsoft Windows Server 2003

Tags: java

I have Microsoft Windows Server 2003. I installed JDK 1.7.0 and JDK 1.6.0 but the version shown by Java version is 1.4.  I can't find any JDK 1.4 or JRE 1.4 folder in `C:\program files\java\`. I also changed `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\program files\java\jre1.7`.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file) thread but didn't help. I know the issue is with JER/JDK compatibility but can't help myself.
I can compile and run my application in Netbeans but can't run this application independently. What might be the issue?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:MYCLASSPackage/ClassName (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
```

Comment: @unhillbilly I used %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" and It worked there was java already installed in system32 folder :( .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you running your "application independently"?  `java.exe ...`?

Specifically point to the version of Java that you'd like to use.  You're probably working against a copy of "java.exe" that exists in the `C:\Windows\System32\` folder, and is using the registry to point to the full 1.4 version.  I could detail this further, but probably couldn't do better than what is already described at http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#MULTIPLES.