# Jar file created in netbeans is not working

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have created a project in Netbeans using my mac , now when i need to deliver the project to client but unfortunately I am not able to run the jar file , I created jar file by
Run->Repeat Build /Run 
But when i am trying to run the project it gives following error

```
    5/17/12 9:54:09.340 AM [0x0-0xa80a8].com.apple.JarLauncher: Exception in thread "main" 
    5/17/12 9:54:09.341 AM [0x0-0xa80a8].com.apple.JarLauncher: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: pos/Login : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Please help that why this error? i am worried because i need to handle the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2466828/1007273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run your jar file using an older version of the JVM.  You compiled under JDK7 and are trying to run under JDK6 or earlier.  You need to set the target Java version in Netbeans to the version matching your client's environment.