# Error creating Android Project with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I downloaded Eclipse Kepler (maybe the latest version) and also the latest version of the Android SDK. I linked Eclipse with SDK, but when I tempt to create an Android Application Project, a NullPointerException occurs at the end of the wizard. This is an image of the error that appears after the click on "Finish". I tried also with Android ADT bundle (Android SDK + Eclipse IDE), but the error always occures.

[image: nullPointerException]

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try updating the android resources using SDK manager?

Comment: Yes, I tried to update all resources, but nothing changes.

Comment: It seems like a java version issue. follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file

Comment: No, nothing to do. I tried to change JDK and JRE in Eclipse. Now I use 1.6 instead 1.7, but the problem remains.

Comment: If you already have some projects in your workspace, you can try to clean it or just create new workspace. That helps for me.