# Bad version number error in classfile

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, solaris

I have created a jar file using eclipse. My jdk version is `1.5.0`. when i run that jar file on linux machine with the same `JDK` it works fine. But when I run this jar on solaris machine with `JDK 1.5.0_14` installed it gives error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

I couldn't get any solution..?

Comment: Usually such exception arise when you compile higher version and running it in lower version of java.

Comment: I know you already told us the version, but can you post the result of `java -version` on both linux and solaris machine?

Comment: And also, remember that not always the same java that runs eclipse is the java that was used by eclipse to compile the app

Comment: `'which java' -version` (and replace ticks with backticks)?

Comment: Beautifully answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file

Comment: on solaris java -version gives  java version "1.5.0_14"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_14-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_14-b03, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when JVM cannot read the classfile. Since JVMs are backward compatible, i.e. support older versions of class files your class is created by compiler newer than JVM you are using.

You are using JVM 1.5, but your code was compiled by compiler of 1.6 or 1.7 (or even probably 1.8?).

So, you should either upgrade your java environment on machine where you are running the application or compile the application with 1.5 compiler. The first way is definitely preferable.