# Getting the following Excepttion while Running TestCases

Tags: java, junit, error-handling

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:425) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number
```

This error usually comes when we try to run a class file with some java version which is higher than the  java version used for compilation.

Try to **use same java version for compilation and runtime**.

Comment: O'Yeah Abhishek but when running java simple application it works fine this error getting when running TestCase(Unit Testing).

Comment: In such case, you need to check the run-time environment under consideration while running a.) program b.) test case. Recommended approach is to fix/use the same java run-time and compiler version before running any java program.

Comment: What to check there.. ?

Comment: 1. Using command line you can check java version with following command:
java -version
----------------------------------------------------------
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)
----------------------------------------------------------

2. If you are using any editor like Eclipse etc., follow the guidelines provided by them.

Comment: Already i did that.. But i don't understand this problem i am getting while running test cases not in another app..