# Getting error(java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version;, offset=6)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to run JUnit test in Eclipse for my code and I have selected Java version 7 for it and try to run it. It is showing me error. I don't know what to do.

Error: `"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; offset=6"`

Comment: Hi, I tried that all steps from "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file", but it didn't work. is there any other way I can solve the problem ?