# Bad version number in .class IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, java-home

I am facing this error while building/importing my project on IntelliJ 2016.2(64).

> Bad version number in .class file

My java home is set to Java 1.5 Update 22 (64 bit). I need to use this version of Java, specifically. Is there a way I can do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file)

Comment: You need a class which was compiled for Java 5.0 or earlier.  I would use the source to recompile it.  I would also make sure I have the most up to date update of Java 5.0 given it is such an old version.

Comment: Point is: normally IntelliJ will be using the java version it is running with for your projects. If you want to build your projects for a different version of java, you have to modify the corresponding entries in your project setup.

Comment: Where exactly do you see that error?